# $http.get causing infinites calls (and errors) until computer crashes

Tags: angularjs

I want to swap an array and get a json file, but don't know why nor where there's something wrong in my code (the service/controller part without an http request works though).

incriminated code

```
(function() {
  (function() {
    var JsonsService;
    JsonsService = function($http) {
      var pizze;
      pizze = [];
      return {
        getPizze: function() {
          $http.get('data/pizze-it.json').then(function(pizze) {
            pizze = pizze.data;
          });
        }
      };
    };
    JsonsService.$inject = ['$http'];
    angular.module('myApp').factory('JsonsService', JsonsService);
  })();

}).call(this);

(function() {
  (function() {
    var JsonsCtrl;
    JsonsCtrl = function(JsonsService) {
      var self;
      self = this;
      self.list = function() {
        return JsonsService.getPizze();
      };
    };
    JsonsCtrl.$inject = ['JsonsService'];
    angular.module('myApp').controller('JsonsCtrl', JsonsCtrl);
  })();

}).call(this);
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GcCdg2VrVUY6mYRPHKMI?p=catalogue)

I removed from app.js the entire block of code that is causing this error (service and controller), and placed it inside DontLoadThis.js (there's some markup to put back into main.html too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't necessarily the definite answer but there's a few things I've noticed that appear wrong.

Starting with your `JsonsService`:

```
JsonsService = function($http) {
    var pizze;
    pizze = [];
    return {
        getPizze: function() {
            $http.get('data/pizze-it.json').then(function(pizze) {
                pizze = pizze.data;
            });
        }
    };
};
```

You're initialising a variable `pizze` but also using the callback variable `pizze` in the `$http.get()`. Instead I suggest:

```
var pizze = [];

...

$http.get('data/pizze-it.json').then(function(json_response) {
    pizze = json_response.data;
});
```

This however is made redundant by the second issue: `JsonsService.getPizze()` doesn't actually return anything. A possible way around this would be to return the promise from `getPizze()` and deal with the result in the controller.

```
// in service
return {
    getPizze: function() {
        return $http.get('data/pizze-it.json');
    }
};

// in controller
JsonsCtrl = function(JsonsService) {
    var self;
    self = this;
    self.list = [];

    JsonsService.getPizze().then(function (json_response) {
        self.list = json_response.data;
    });
};
```

Comment: Updated the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GcCdg2VrVUY6mYRPHKMI?p=preview), the infinite error loop has gone away, but still I'm not receiving data

Comment: The issue is now in the `ng-repeat`. You should use `item in jsons.list`. [See me!](http://plnkr.co/edit/bAIbUQ7WYwwNVtHwGeOY?p=preview)

Comment: Oh nice it works :D but please, tell me a thing: how can it work now, if getPizze() isn't call anywhere?

Comment: Great! `getPizze()` is now called when the `JsonsCtrl` is first instantiated (called). Remember `JsonsCtrl` is a function itself so somewhere in Angular it's internally doing`JsonsCtrl()` which will run everything in the function body (which will include `getPizze()`!)

Comment: Everything's clear now :D thank you so much, really!